# Can i import ost file outlook without loosing my e-mails?

Tags: file, outlook, copy

I need to import my ost file.

I move the email into an outlook directory to reduce space in 
inbox.

These files are removed automatically from server but I can save them in my local outlook.

I was wondering if I uninstall outlook and install it again and import this ost file, will i lose my files?

I read that you can not import an ost file... If so, have I lost all my mails?

Thanks, kind regard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OST files are a local copy of your Exchange mailbox. You cannot access OST files the way you access PST files. If your messages were in an OST files, that means they are in your Exchange mailbox.

That being said, this is not a programming question. Ask questions like this at SuperUser.